# rxjs5 - filtering array of objects by observable that each object contains

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I have an array that looks like this

```
[
  {
    name: 'foo'
    filter: Observable.of(true)
  },
  {
    name: 'bar'
    filter: Observable.of(false)
  }
]
```

and I want to return only items whose `filter` resolves in true, how would I do that in the most efficient and reactive way? I'm using rxjs5 beta2.

---

Note that it's a pseudocode for simplicity sake, in my real case filter is actually an object, that is passed to a validation function, which returns an observable that resolves in `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatMap each item in the array to an Observable stream that will emit a version of the item that replaced the `filter` property of type `Observable<bool>` with a `bool` property.

```
const data$ = Rx.Observable.from(arr)

  // Convert each item's filter property to type bool
  .flatMap(x => x.filter.map(condition => Object.assign({}, x, { filter: condition })))

  // Now we can just filter over the filter property, which is of type bool.
  .filter(x => x.filter)

  // Each item emitted will have a filter value of true
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in RxJS 4 that make this easy:  map and Rx.helpers.defaultComparer.  first map sends each item from the iterable separately and the defaultComparer will do the deep check for you.

```
var comparer = Rx.helpers.defaultComparer;
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

const arr = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    filter: Observable.of(true)
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    filter: Observable.of(false)
  }
];

const data$ = Observable.from(arr)
  .map(each => each)
  .filter(each => comparer(each.filter, Observable.of(true)))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// prints Object {name: "foo", filter: FromArrayObservable} to my console
```

For some reason this defaultComparer is not in five at this time.  Maybe there is a new name for the helper because it is not said to be deprecated in 4 or maybe it has not be migrated over yet or is not at .helpers.